# Flutter app apk does not work properly on phone but works well on emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Flutter app apk does not work properly on phone but works well on emulator.Clicking the button to add data to the sqflite database does not work or  when I change the application language.I've tried all the suggestions I found on the internet but it still doesn't work I don't understand where is the problem.Works great in the emulator but When I install the apk and install it on my phone, it doesn't work. Flutter run -v

```
> [ +214 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +132 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 9b2d32b605630f28625709ebd9d78ab3016b2bf6
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git tag --points-at HEAD
[ +144 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at HEAD
[        ] 1.22.6
[  +17 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +97 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] origin/stable
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +83 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +167 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[ +137 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +5 ms] stable
[ +175 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +19 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[  +12 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +78 ms] executing: C:\Users\raghi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[ +101 ms] List of devices attached
[   +8 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[ +164 ms] No supported devices connected.
[  +34 ms] "flutter run" took 511ms.
[  +51 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:353:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:933:11)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:836:33)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart)
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:29)
           #6      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #7      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #8      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
           #9      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1550:10)
           #10     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:18)
           #11     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:825:20)
           #12     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
           #13     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:335:21)
           #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #16     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #17     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #18     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #19     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #20     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #21     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #22     FlutterVersion.checkFlutterVersionFreshness (package:flutter_tools/src/version.dart)
           #23     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #24     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #25     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #26     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #27     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #28     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #29     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #30     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #31     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #32     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #33     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #34     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #35     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #36     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #37     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
           
           
>[ +396 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 374ms
>[  +15 ms] Running shutdown hooks
>[   +2 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
>[   +2 ms] exiting with code 1
```

I'm just getting the above error.I created a new project and got that error even in the flutter demo app So it's not a bug with my code.Please help me, I've been dealing with this for 3 days

I'm getting this error with Flutter build apk.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform:
```

But I do not get errors with these codes, but the apk does not work correctly.

```
flutter build apk --debug

flutter build apk --profile

flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: There's some things you can review. 1. Check permissions defined on AndroidManifest.xml; 2. Check if minSdkVersion at android/app/build.gradle is compatible with your phone; 3. The error contains this message "No supported devices connected.". It may be something to take a look :)

Comment: @siega Please help me,  * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform:

Comment: What did you do with the new project? Are you adding some specific dependency? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @siega I just did it to see if the mistake was in my code or in flutter. debug.apk works great but release.apk doesn't work properly. It's a very complicated situation because I don't get an error and I don't know where I went wrong. It works in the emulator, but is it not working on the real phone because of the faulty code?Is this possible?Where should I look for my bug?

Comment: I'll try to help you with this... 1. Post the result of flutter doctor -v. 2. Post the result of flutter devices command. 3. Get you phone ID in the previous command, run your app with flutter run -d <your_device_id> -v and post it here

Comment: @siega Thank you so much for being here and wanting to help.I solved the problem.I don't understand what the problem is but it was definitely caused by Flutter.Been looking for 3 days what the problem was, 3 days wasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why the problem is caused, but I took care of it.I created a new project with a different name and I rebuilt the files of my old project one by one and copied the contents.I re-downloaded all packages under dependencies in new versions.And lastly I added the internet permission `androidManifest.xml` even if my application is not using internet. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

This issue most likely occurred after updating Flutter. Always check after updating Flutter